# How to pause a loop in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I need to pause a spacebar spamming macro with a key like f10, here is my code

```
c::
Loop
{
    if not GetKeyState("c", "P")
        break
    Sleep 25 ; ms
    Send {space}
}
return
```

I tried to add a pause similar to the getkeystate in and out of the loop but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

```
q::
Loop
{ 
Click, right,
Mousemove, 0, 110, 5, Rel
click, left
Mousemove,   350, -473, 5, rel
click, left
Mousemove,  -350,  363, 5, rel
}
return

#p::Pause,Toggle
```

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/95308-endless-loop-with-hotkey-pause/

Answer (score 1):

I always do something to the extent of this:

```
c::
Toggle := !Toggle
While Toggle {
    ; do whatever you need to do here
}
Return
```

An additional advantage here is that there's only one hotkey to remember. Press once to begin the endless loop. Press again to stop.